# values getting repeated in object after regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

Could someone tell me why particular key value getting repeat in object?

I've data like below getting from response like below.

```
var data = {
      "sub": {
        "LoadTime on linkedShip": "01:25:00 AM",
        "business Limit": "300",
        "avoid goods": "50",
        "avoid goods_Group": "100",
        "isPermanent": "['permLinkAccount']",
        "transport Limit": "1",
        "hasDailySlot": "1"
      }
    };
```

trying to replace `"isPermanent": "['permLinkAccount']"` to `"isPermanent":"permLinkAccount"` without changing other stuffs in object.

```
if (data.sub.hasOwnProperty("isPermanent")) {
  
  data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/[\[\]']/g,"permLinkAccount"));
  console.log('data', data);
}
```

but getting like
`isPermanent: "permLinkAccountpermLinkAccountpermLinkAccountpermLinkAccountpermLinkAccount"` instead of `"isPermanent":"permLinkAccount"`

I need like

```
    LoadTime on linkedShip: "01:25:00 AM"
    avoid goods: "50"
    avoid goods_Group: "100"
    business Limit: "300"
    hasDailySlot: "1"
    isPermanent: "permLinkAccount"
    transport Limit: "1"
```

[fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sathya_da/j091mbpq/31/)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just parsing the JSON into an object and work with the object, it's easier.

```
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
if (dataObj.hasOwnProperty("isPermanent")) {
  dataObj.isPermanent = "permLinkAccount"
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is the OP doesn't know what the value of "permLinkAccount" is ahead of time...

Comment: @Gabriel Lupu this one so easy

Answer (score 2):

Per your regex you are replacing [, ', and ] with permalinkAccount (hence the result) where you want to actually filter them out of the expression.

Just use and empty string as a replacement instead.

```js
console.log("['permLinkAccount']".replace(/[\[\]']/g, ""))
```

Or

```js
console.log("['permLinkAccount']".replace(/\W/g, ""))
```